# Deadlock occurs in downloading files with segments in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download, deadlock, segment

I'm trying to find why sometimes deadlock happens when downloading a file by splitting into multiple segments. I'm using async/await, but this doesn't work every time. Any ideas on how can i identify the problem?

```
 IEnumerable<Task<bool>> downloadTasksQuery = from segment in job.Segments select RunSegment(segment);
 Task<bool>[] downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToArray();
 bool[] lengths = await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

after the await many times doesn't come back.

And the RunSegment() method

Method to download the segment using http client.

```
        private async Task<bool> RunSegment(DownloadSegment segment)
        {
            try
            {
                int TotalBytesReadedInSession=0;
                if (segment.LocalStream == null) return false;
                segment.Status = DownloadStatus.Starting;
                segment.IsBusy = true;
                segment.Error = string.Empty;
                segment.Speed = 0;
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, job.Url);
                request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(segment.Start + segment.BytesDownloaded, segment.End);
                var response = await job.DownloadManager.httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    DateTime dtInitial = DateTime.Now;
                    var buffer = new byte[job.DownloadManager.bufferSize];
                    var isMoreDataToRead = true;
                    segment.Status = DownloadStatus.Downloading;
                    segment.IsBusy = true;
                    job.Status = DownloadStatus.Downloading;
                    do
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                            var read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                            TotalBytesReadedInSession += read;
                            if((DateTime.Now - dtInitial).TotalSeconds >= 1)
                            {
                                segment.Speed = TotalBytesReadedInSession / (DateTime.Now-dtInitial).TotalSeconds;
                            }
                            if (read == 0 || (segment.End - (segment.Start + segment.BytesDownloaded)) <= 0)
                            {
                                isMoreDataToRead = false;
                                if ((segment.End - (segment.Start + segment.BytesDownloaded)) <= 0)
                                {
                                    segment.BytesDownloaded = (segment.End - segment.Start);
                                    segment.Status = DownloadStatus.Completed;
                                    segment.IsBusy = false;
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Write data on disk.
                                if (segment.End > 0 && (segment.Start + segment.BytesDownloaded + read) > segment.End)
                                {
                                    // adjust the 'readSize' to write only necessary bytes
                                    read = Convert.ToInt32((segment.End - segment.Start - segment.BytesDownloaded));
                                }
                                if (read > 0)
                                {
                                    lock (segment.LocalStream)
                                    {
                                        segment.LocalStream.Seek(segment.Start + segment.BytesDownloaded, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                    }
                                    await segment.LocalStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);

                                    segment.BytesDownloaded += read;
                                    segment.Progress = ((segment.BytesDownloaded) * 1d) / ((segment.End - segment.Start) * 1d) * 100;
                                }
                                else if ((segment.Start + segment.BytesDownloaded) >= segment.End) { segment.IsBusy = false; segment.Status = DownloadStatus.Completed; return true; }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            segment.Speed = 0;
                            if (ex is OperationCanceledException)
                            {
                                segment.Error = string.Empty;
                                segment.Status = DownloadStatus.Stopped;
                                segment.IsBusy = false;
                                return false;
                            }
                            segment.CurrentTryError = +1;
                            segment.Status = DownloadStatus.Error;
                            segment.Error = ex.Message;
                            if (stream != null) { stream.Close(); stream.Dispose(); }
                            await Task.Delay(3000);
                            if ((segment.CurrentTryError - 1) > job.DownloadManager.MaximumTryErrorCounts) { segment.IsBusy = false; return false; }
                            return await RunSegment(segment).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                    } while (isMoreDataToRead);
                }
            }           
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
                segment.Speed = 0;
                segment.Status = DownloadStatus.Error;
                segment.Error = ex.Message;
                segment.IsBusy = false;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: How many of these are you normally running and is the endpoint your own or is it likely that they are throttling you because you are hitting them with 100 simultaneous requests and therefore look like a DDOS person?  If it is not yours you probably need to loop where you only run like 5-10 tasks at a time.  This is all guesswork based on what I cannot see.

Comment: It's not mine, segments is max 10. It happens with different nr. of segment like 4,6 too. The problem is that when it happens nothing comes back, not error, not time out, nothing

Comment: Show the code for job.DownloadManager.httpclient , if that is a single httpclient you might instead have single HTTPRequests in each task because I would guess you could deadlock there depending on what is behind the curtain.

Comment: It's a single http client instance in order to reuse like this:

Comment: public readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20) };

Comment: Looking deeper that should not be an issue, do these start dropping into error status before the deadlock or just curiously deadlocked?

Comment: just deadlocks, no errors at all. I've tried with instantiate new httpclient  before every segment but same results

Answer (score 0):

could it be because the filestream? I create a file stream before downloading. all segments are writed in same file

Comment: My guess would be yes. You probably need to have a final task that combines the file back together because seeking while one is writing would surely cause some issues.  Depending on the size you could maybe do it in memory, but not if these are huge files.

Comment: Or you could lock on something at a higher level.  It looks like your lock is probably specific to segment when it should probably be specific to file.

Comment: I've tested with only one segment and still happens sometimes. No timeout, no error return nothing. It's wird

Answer (score 0):

I would guess actually that this entire section should be locked at the file level (where multiple segments are not writing at the same time) and you might be okay.

```
     lock (job.FileLock)
     {
          segment.LocalStream.Seek(segment.Start + segment.BytesDownloaded, SeekOrigin.Begin);     
          await segment.LocalStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
     }
```